# Corona virus information app | Simple React project with an API

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm working on a simple react App (my first) ,this is information tracer for coronavirus ,

but i unable to fetch countries names , i get numbers instant !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztBCH.png

this is link of app files : https://github.com/jgbijlsma/corona-dashboard

and this is code to fetch countries names :

```
async getData() {
    const defaultRes = await Axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api");
    const countriesRes = await Axios.get(
      "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries"
    );
    const countries = Object.keys(countriesRes.data.countries);
```

can please help !

Comment: Please post the code that retrieves the country list. We're not going to trawl through your github code. I suggest you debug and determine whether country names are being returned and you're displaying the wrong thing.

Comment: thank you i'll make some change in code and post it here

Comment: hello 

i update question with code that fetch countries names , issue is solved when i replace

    const countries = Object.keys(countriesRes.data.countries);
with 
const resCountries = await Axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries");
        const countries = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < resCountries.data.countries.length; i++){
            countries.push(resCountries.data.countries[i].name);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The country data returned has this format:

[image]

Make sure you parse this correctly. (I'm not sure sure, but I think I didn't see that you parse the `name` field, just the key, which is an integer)

Comment: ok i will double check and inform you

Comment: hello , thank you for your answer it help match 

the code i was use to fetch countries names was :

    const countries = Object.keys(countriesRes.data.countries);

issue is solved when i replace it with :

 
const resCountries = await Axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries");
        const countries = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < resCountries.data.countries.length; i++){
            countries.push(resCountries.data.countries[i].name);
        }

Comment: You should really post this as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I really would like to do that but because this question is closed "i don't know why ? " i can't find box of answer